# Problems updating and re-installing VLC in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: dependencies, vlc

I can't seem to fix or update, upgrade VLC at all; this is what I get when trying to install, I had VLC before, but was not working properly so I uninstalled it; then I tried to install it again to have the full properties. So now I cannot install as I get this message, I have tried everything and have checked with your site for additional info; any suggestions to someone who is new to Ubuntu and Linux altogether?

```
# Package dependencies cannot be resolved
# This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are  missing or not installable. 
# Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time

# The following packages have unmet dependencies:

vlc:  
Depends: vlc-nox (= 1.1.12-2~oneiric1) but 2.1.0~~git20121022+r2158-0~r88~oneiric1 is to be installed  
Depends: libaa1 (>= 1.4p5) but 1.4p5-38build1 is to be installed  
Depends: libavcodec-extra-53 (>= 4:0.7-1) but 4:0.7.6ubuntu0.11.10.1+medibuntu1 is to be installed  
Depends: libavutil-extra-51 (>= 4:0.7-1) but 4:0.7.6ubuntu0.11.10.1+medibuntu1 is to be installed  
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.8) but 2.13-20ubuntu5.3 is to be installed  
Depends: libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1) but 2.4.4-2ubuntu1.2 is to be installed  
Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.6.1-9ubuntu3 is to be installed  
Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.7.0~beta1) but 4:4.7.4-0ubuntu8.2 is to be installed  
Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.5.3) but 4:4.7.4-0ubuntu8.2 is to be installed  
Depends: libsdl-image1.2 (>= 1.2.10) but 1.2.10-2.1 is to be installed  
Depends: libsdl1.2debian (>= 1.2.10-1) but 1.2.14-6.1ubuntu4 is to be installed  
Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) but 4.6.1-9ubuntu3 is to be installed  
Depends: libxcb-xv0 (>= 1.2) but 1.7-3 is to be installed  
Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.3.3.dfsg) but 1:1.2.3.4.dfsg-3ubuntu3 is to be installed`
```

Answer (score 2):

I've had this happen to me, too. You'll have to open a terminal.
The first thing is to check for broken dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

If that doesn't work, I would purge vlc and reinstall:

```
sudo apt-get purge vlc*
sudo aptitude purge $(dpkg -l|grep ^rc|awk '{ print $2 }')
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

I'm not sure if this will work, but let us know and I can adjust depending on your results.